# Getting a diff between two heavily reformatted C files

Tags: c

I recently received a relatively important feature addition to some software I maintain from someone. Unfortunately, rather than providing a diff, he instead just gave me his entire source tree, and to make matters worse, it seems that he's used some sort of code prettifier that goes far beyond anything I've used or seen, including things like

- Inserting and removing spaces at various points inside the lines.
- Breaking some conditionals into bracketed blocks, making some into single-line conditionals, and making some into conditionals with a line break but no brackets.
- Moving some combined statements onto separate lines, and combining some separated statements into single lines.
- Inserting and removing linebreaks inside places like function arguments.
- Etc

Running indent (BSD) on files from his version and the older version doesn't bring them that close to each other. Using astyle doesn't work well either. In either case, there are still quite a few remnants of the different formatting styles.

Is there any C formatter that would essentially remove as much formatting as possible, and then format the code consistently? Or is there any way to get a formatter to do this? It doesn't need to look terribly nice, I just need to be able to get a reasonable diff so that I can see what he actually changed.

Comment: Can you send it back to him and ask him to adhere to the existing formatting standards?

Comment: or get hin to two checkins the original code reformatted as by him and then the changes

Comment: As a warning to others reading this, or thinking about refactoring code that they'll later submit somewhere: it turned out that it was easiest for us to *entirely reimplement* the work from scratch, completely ignoring his contribution, as it was simply too hard to reliably find out what was changed in his version.

Answer (score 4):

I would try deleting as much whitespace as possible with `tr -s ' \t\r\n' ' '` or equivalent, and then feeding the result back into `indent`.  (Can't do tr -d, unfortunately, because that would damage token boundaries.)

Comment: The problem with doing this is that it won't deal with preprocessor directives or // comments, but it does seem that slight changes to deal with that would work, and I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

[uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) is another option you could try - the extreme configurability is a bit overwhelming, but it's capable of doing most (if not all) of the things you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The reformatters that come with Netbeans and Eclipse C devolpment packs are very aggressive, maybe you could try them.

Answer (score 1):

You can preprocess both files and then diff them.

Comment: I think that is exactly what he did xD

Comment: Unfortunately, a preprocessor like GNU cpp only deals with macros, rather than redoing the formatting, unless I've missed an option somewhere.